# Nginx Reverse Proxy on nixOS returns 404 when trying to load css/js

Tags: docker, go, nginx, reverse-proxy, nixos

I've set up a `nixOS` to run an `nginx` as a reverse proxy for a docker-container. In the docker-container runs an `golang`-server which handles `/` with a function and also return files from the two folders `static` and `js`. It runs on port 8181. The code for this looks like this:

```golang
func main() {
        static := http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))
        js := http.FileServer(http.Dir("js"))
        http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", static))
        http.Handle("/js/", http.StripPrefix("/js/", js))
        // Register function to "/"
        http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
        fmt.Println("Server is starting...")
        err := http.ListenAndServe("0.0.0.0:8181", nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("cannot listen and server", err)
        }
        
}
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        wd, err := os.Getwd()
        var static = filepath.Join(wd, "static")
        var index = filepath.Join(static, "index.html")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("cannot get working directory", err)
        }

        // Check if the request is an OPTIONS preflight request
        if r.Method == "OPTIONS" {
                // Respond with status OK to preflight requests
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
                return
        }

        // POST-Request
        if r.Method == http.MethodPost {
              // do something
        } else {
                // Loading the index.html without any data
                tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(index)
                err = tmpl.Execute(w, nil) // write response to w
                if err != nil {
                        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
                        log.Fatal("problem with parsing the index template ", err)
                }

        }
}
```

The structure of my app looks like this.

```
├── web
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── go.mod
│   ├── server.go
│   └── static
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── style.css
│   │   └── table.html
│   └── js
│       └── htmx.min.js
```

The configuration of the `nginx`-section in the `configuration.nix` looks like this.

```hs
  services.nginx = {
    enable = true;
    recommendedGzipSettings = true;
    recommendedOptimisation = true;
    recommendedProxySettings = true;
    recommendedTlsSettings = true;
    virtualHosts."myapp" = {
      sslCertificate = "/etc/ssl/nginx/ssl.cert";
      sslCertificateKey = "/etc/ssl/nginx/ssl.key";
      sslTrustedCertificate = "/etc/ssl/nginx/ssl.chain";
      forceSSL = true; # Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
      locations = {
        "/myapp" = { proxyPass = "http://localhost:8181/"; };
      };
      extraConfig = ''
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      '';
    };

  };
```

When I address the url `https://server/myapp` the `index.html` will load, but the `style.css` and the `htmx.min.js` will return a 404.

When addressing the container with the port 8181 instead of the url (`http://server:8181`), everything loads as usual.

I expect nginx to redirect requests for loading css and js to the container.

**EDIT:**
The exact error is: `GET https://server.name/static/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404` even though I am accessing `https://server.name/myapp`.

Another important information is that, I want run multiple containers this way over the same reverse proxy. So directing als `css`- or `js`-files to the same location won't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the css/js references in the `index.html` file. It's very likely that you're referencing them by absolute paths like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/style.css" />
    <script src="/js/htmx.min.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

A quick fix is to replace them with relative paths:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./static/style.css" />
    <script src="./js/htmx.min.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

This approach is error-prone. A better approach is to modify the app to serve the content at `/myapp`:

```golang
http.Handle("/myapp/static/", http.StripPrefix("/myapp/static/", static))
http.Handle("/myapp/js/", http.StripPrefix("/myapp/js/", js))
http.HandleFunc("/myapp/", indexHandler)
```

And modify the reference paths in the `index.html` file:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/myapp/static/style.css" />
    <script src="/myapp/js/htmx.min.js"></script>
  </head>
</html>
```

And then modify the nginx configuration:

```
locations = {
  "/myapp/" = { proxyPass = "http://localhost:8181/myapp/"; };
};
```

With this approach, no matter the reverse proxy is used or not, the web app will always be served at the uri `/myapp/`, which should make it easy to maintain.

Comment: Replacing the links with relative paths did not work. But serving all the content over `/myapp` works for me.

Comment: `Replacing the links with relative paths did not work`, that's weird. Have added a [<base>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) element to the page? If yes, remove it and try again.

Comment: I did not place a `<base>` element on my page.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! Then I don't know why the relative paths approach does not work.